# CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:25060: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python-2.7, ip-address

I am working on installation of CDRTOOL + freeradius + mediaproxy +opensips.
I am stuck on installation of mediaproxy while other 3 are completed.

when I run mediaproxy-dispatcher ,

/usr/bin/media-dispatcher --no-fork

I get following error:-

```
INFO     [main] Starting MediaProxy Dispatcher 2.6.6
INFO     [main] Twisted is using epollreactor
CRITICAL [main] failed to create MediaProxy Dispatcher: Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:25060: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
ERROR    [main] Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR    [main]   File "/usr/bin/media-dispatcher", line 53, in <module>
ERROR    [main]     dispatcher = Dispatcher()
ERROR    [main]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mediaproxy/dispatcher.py", line 491, in __init__
ERROR    [main]     self.relay_listener = reactor.listenTLS(dispatcher_port, self.relay_factory, self.tls_context, interface=dispatcher_addr)
ERROR    [main]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnutls/interfaces/twisted/__init__.py", line 351, in listenTLS
ERROR    [main]     p.startListening()
ERROR    [main]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 980, in startListening
ERROR    [main]     raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)
ERROR    [main] CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:25060: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
```

I am stuck here for 2-3 days....can anyone help me, plzz ??

this is error i am getting after killing the process and rerunning it :-

```
root@santo-VirtualBox:~# kill 1308
root@santo-VirtualBox:~# /usr/bin/media-dispatcher --no-fork
INFO     [main] Starting MediaProxy Dispatcher 2.6.6
INFO     [main] Twisted is using epollreactor
^CINFO     [main] Received KeyboardInterrupt, exiting.

GARBAGE:
gc: collectable <tuple 0x7fe92ca67950>
gc: collectable <StgDict 0x7fe92cf4e898>
gc: collectable <_ctypes.PyCArrayType 0x5590a63665c0>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 0x7fe92ca6b878>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 0x7fe92ca6b8c0>
gc: collectable <tuple 0x7fe932a62e10>
gc: collectable <tuple 0x7fe92ca67d50>
gc: collectable <StgDict 0x7fe92cf4ea40>
gc: collectable <_ctypes.PyCArrayType 0x5590a636d900>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 0x7fe92ca6b998>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 0x7fe92ca6b9e0>
gc: collectable <tuple 0x7fe930e53c00>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 0x7fe92ca6ba28>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 0x7fe92ca6ba70>

COLLECTABLE CYCLES:
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'> -> (<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'>, <type '_ctypes.Array'>, <type '_ctypes._CData'>, <type 'object'>) -> <class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'>
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'> -> {'raw': <attribute 'raw' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '__module__': 'ctypes', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '_length_': 256, '_type_': <class 'ctypes.c_char'>, '__doc__': None, 'value': <attribute 'value' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>} -> <attribute 'value' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects> -> <class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'>
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'> -> {'raw': <attribute 'raw' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '__module__': 'ctypes', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '_length_': 256, '_type_': <class 'ctypes.c_char'>, '__doc__': None, 'value': <attribute 'value' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>} -> <attribute 'raw' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects> -> <class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'>
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'> -> {'raw': <attribute 'raw' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '__module__': 'ctypes', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '_length_': 256, '_type_': <class 'ctypes.c_char'>, '__doc__': None, 'value': <attribute 'value' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>} -> <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects> -> <class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'>
<class 'gnutls.connection.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1'> -> (<class 'gnutls.connection.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1'>, <type '_ctypes.Array'>, <type '_ctypes._CData'>, <type 'object'>) -> <class 'gnutls.connection.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1'>
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'> -> {'raw': <attribute 'raw' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '__module__': 'ctypes', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>, '_length_': 256, '_type_': <class 'ctypes.c_char'>, '__doc__': None, 'value': <attribute 'value' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects>} -> <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_char_Array_256' objects> -> <class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_256'>
<class 'gnutls.connection.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1'> -> {'__module__': 'gnutls.connection', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1' objects>, '_length_': 1, '_type_': <class 'gnutls.library.types.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int'>, '__doc__': None} -> <attribute '__weakref__' of 'LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1' objects> -> <class 'gnutls.connection.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1'>
<class 'gnutls.connection.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1'> -> {'__module__': 'gnutls.connection', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1' objects>, '_length_': 1, '_type_': <class 'gnutls.library.types.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int'>, '__doc__': None} -> <attribute '__dict__' of 'LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1' objects> -> <class 'gnutls.connection.LP_gnutls_x509_crt_int_Array_1'>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check 1: Is port available?**

In a development environment, this error generally when a server serving(holding) a port resource gets crashed and did not release that port.

```sh
netstat -lntu
```

Refer to https://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux

Every time you get a port occupied error, please follow this step.

**Check 2: Python Package Bugs?**

Try to upgrade or downgrade your python package version. There were some bugs that might be related to OS, & other dependencies.

```sh
pip install my_package_name==1.2.3
```

I have check the source code of `mediaproxy/dispatcher.py` and not able to find those lines of code in the latest branch of that repo.

Comment: i have done that...killing the process using its PID .After killing the process , when I run it , it only throws garbage collectable i.e, gc

Comment: i have attached the output after killing the process and rerunning it @Sampath

Comment: @santoshkumar - JFI, I consider this new GC error as progress only. Good Job !!